# Target overrides the `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` build setting

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Here is my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'TestApp' do
  ...
end
```

After `pod install`I get the following errors:

```
[!] The `TestApp [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TestApp/Pods-TestApp.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `TestApp [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TestApp/Pods-TestApp.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

**How do I resolve this problem?**

Comment: What's your question? Did you try following the instructions it gave you?

Comment: I have no idea what to do here. Could you please help?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

1. Select your project
2. Switch to your project 's `Build Settings` panel.
3. Search for `Other Swift Flags`
4. Now you may see the value of `Other Swift Flags` shows in **BOLD**

(**BOLD** also means this value is being overridden)

[image]

As the warnings showing in terminal:

> Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.

You can make the compiler happy in these two ways:

Option 1:

Double click the `Other Swift Flags` value area and replace the value with `$(inherited)`

Option 2:

Select the `Other Swift Flags` panel to make it highlight. Then press the **Delete** Button in your keyboard and now the font will become *THIN*, instead of **BOLD**.

Comment: Also works for ``ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`` setting.

Comment: Also works for `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` :)

Comment: Well, I would say this solves this specific warning, but can generate dozens of other problems if the (now deleted) swift flags _have been used_. Just deleting them mindlessly is not a _general_ way to handle this. If those values where used for conditional compilation (like DEBUG or RELEASE) then this values could be moved to the "Active compilation conditions" build setting instead.

Comment: A third option is to add the $(inherited) flag as an additional flag instead of replacing if you need to maintain your existing custom flag,

Comment: This: **(Double click the Other Swift Flags value area and replace the value with $(inherited))** worked for me when I had problems converting from XCode 3 to Xcode 4.2 in a project that uses cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem where I have to use multiple targets and cocoapods

1. Staging / Development
2. Production

You can add multiple swift flags in targets --> Build Settings ---> Other Swift flags.